# Где поставить запятые («после того как»)?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, и

Она недолго поговорила с одноклассницей насчёт биологии и(,) после того(,) как ушли те, кто пишет английский, пошли и они.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Она недолго поговорила с одноклассницей насчёт биологии, и, после того как ушли те, кто пишет английский, пошли и они.*

Перед союзом ***и*** нужно поставить запятую, так как он соединяет два предложения (*она поговорила*, *они пошли*), второе из которых имеет придаточное предложение с союзом ***после того как***.

Между союзами ***и*** и ***после того как*** запятая нужна.

[**Постановка запятой при встрече союзов**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188)

> ...рядом могут оказаться **сочинительный и подчинительный** союзы. Сравните два предложения:
>
> *Женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, **и, хотя** слова ее были привычными для Сабурова, от них вдруг защемило сердце* (Симонов).
>
> *Женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, **и хотя** слова ее были привычными для Сабурова, **но** от них вдруг защемило сердце.*
>
> Если в сложном предложении рядом оказались сочинительный и подчинительный союзы (И и ХОТЯ, И и КАК и др.), то нужно выяснить, нет ли после придаточной части соотносительных слов ТО, ТАК или еще одного сочинительного союза (А, НО, ОДНАКО и др.). Запятая ставится только тогда, когда эти слова после придаточной части отсутствуют.

Что касается запятой внутри союза ***после того как***, то её ставить не нужно: см. [**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ В КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ С СОСТАВНЫМИ ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3).

> В том случае, если составной союз целиком входит в придаточную часть, знаки препинания ставятся следующим образом:
>
> В) Если придаточная часть предшествует главной – запятая ставится только после всего придаточного предложения.

Отсутствию запятой внутри союза также способствует интонация: не стоит делать паузу после первой части союза и ударение на ***того***, так как далее идёт ещё одно придаточное, относящееся к указательному местоимению ***те***. Предложение и без того немного перегружено грамматическими основами и акцентами.